# Python 3.8.x Intra and Extra Imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, importerror

When defining multiple python 3 packages in a project, I cannot determine how to configure the environment (using VS Code) such that I can run a file in any package with intra-package imports without breaking extra-package imports.

Example with absolute paths:

```
src/
  foo/
    a.py
    b.py
  goo/
    c.py

# b.py contents
from foo.a import *

# c.py contents
from foo.b import *
```

where PYTHONPATH="${workspaceFolder}\src", so it should be able to see the foo and goo directories.

I can run c.py, but running b.py gives a ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'foo'".

Modifying b.py to use relative paths:

```
# modified b.py contents
from a import *
```

Then allows me to run b.py, but attempting to then run c.py gives a ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'b'".

I have also added __init__.py files to foo/ and goo/ directories, but the errors still occurs.

I did set the cwd in the launch.json file to be the ${workspaceFolder} directory, if that is relevant.

Comment: how do you run the code? via integrated terminal in vscode?

Comment: @tyson.wu yes, through the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I was trying to avoid, but does work in-case there are no better solutions, is putting each individual package-dependency onto the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

E.g., "${workspaceFolder}\src;${workspaceFolder}\foo" when running c.py.

But this is not an easily scalable solution and is also something that needs to be tracked across project changes, so I do not think it is a particularly good or pythonic solution.

Comment: Not tested, but I believe this has the potential for namespace collisions as well.

Comment: There are also issues with "isinstance" checks. E.g., a class imported by "from foo.a import T" is not the same as "from a import T" type-wise, as one is type foo.a.T and the other is a.T.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can find it didn't work if you try to print the current path. It just add ".." to the path instead of the parent directory.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.append('..')
print(sys.path)
```

So, what we have to do is add the path of module we used to "sys" in path.

**Here we have three ways:**

1. Put the written .py file into the directory that has been added to the system environment variable;
2. Create a new .pth file under \Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages.

Write the path of the module in this new .pth file , one path per line.

3. Using the pythonpath environment variable as upstairs said.

Then we can use this two ways to import :

```
sys. path. append ('a').
sys. path. insert (0, 'a')
```